# Div appear behind a link on hover? - Jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've read 10 + answers on here but I still haven't been able to get it to work using jquery! I am pretty new to javascript/jquery so I am having many issues. Any help would be appreciated!

I have a small image that when I hover over it I need a 100% height box to appear behind it (similar to the left arrow when you open a new tab in Google Chrome).  Here is my css:

```
#rightarrow {
    background: url("images/rightarrow.png") no-repeat;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 45%;
    right: 3%;
    height: 73px;
    width: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
}

#rightbox {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: .5;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 8%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}
```

and here is the jsfiddle of my jquery/other things:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUbUP/2/)

I would be grateful for any help! I have tried linking my javascript in an external style sheet and also in the header with the full code, and also above my div in the main body, but it won't work. I'm pretty sure I'm referencing the external javascript file correctly,  but I may just be doing some dumb mistake. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot see the `#rightbox` element inside your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the elements in JQuery function as classname, eg:

```
$(".rightarrow")
```

when you should use reference as id, as you do in css:

```
$("#rightarrow")
```

It's not required that you use id or classname strictly, but you should use consistent selector both in css and in jquery functions.

--EDIT--

Here it is:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="rightarrow">test</a>
<div id="rightbox"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#rightarrow").hover(function (e) {
        $("#rightbox").show();
    },
         function (e) {
        $("#rightbox").hide();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#rightarrow {
    background: url("images/rightarrow.png") no-repeat;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 45%;
    right: 3%;
    height: 73px;
    width: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
}

#rightbox {
    background-color: #fff000;
    opacity: .5;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 8%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    display:none;
}
```

Note that JQuery hide/show functions toggles the css "display" property, not "visibility".
So I had to change "visibility:hidden" to "display:none".
Note that "visibility" property gives more overhead on the rendering of the page, so avoid using it where it's not needed, and prefer "display" where applicable.

Read the difference here:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I just changed these but it's still not working :(

Comment: copy pasted all of that :( still not working. maybe some of my other code is conflicting with it

Comment: Have you added the JQuery framework in JSFiddle? It was missing. http://jsfiddle.net/WkAyE/

Comment: I think I have it correctly, I have script src="js/jquery.js" in my head tag -- i have also tried it in different places in my html file

Comment: Did you check the fiddle link in my last comment? It works there!

Comment: Do you check the console log? Maybe you are not running that javascript on document ready? Have a look at my answer, I just updated the JS section

Comment: I ran it in chrome console and it said that "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in my file -- hmmm

Comment: That's exactly the point: you should wait for JQuery to load by calling your function on document ready

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28642/discussion-between-shanling-and-littlesweetseas)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- There is no box in your HTML.
- Use `.` or `#` to select element by class or identity respectively, but not both. `$('.#rightarrow')` is not valid.
- To hide something that you want to use jQuery to show, use `display: none;` and not `visibility`.
- If you want to use jQuery in a jsFiddle, add it as a framework.

[Have a look at this update :)](http://jsfiddle.net/dUbUP/16/)

Answer (score 1):

firstly require the jquery scripts and use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //hide the rightbox
   $('#rightbox').hide();
      $("#rightarrow").hover(function () {
      //if mouse enter
      $('#rightbox').show();
   }, function(){
      //if mouse out
      $('#rightbox').hide();
   });
});
```

and here is the css

```
 #rightarrow {
background: url("images/rightarrow.png") no-repeat;
white-space: nowrap;
top: 45%;
right: 3%;
height: 73px;
width: 25px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 6;
 }

 #rightbox {
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.5;
white-space: nowrap;
top: 0%;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 8%;
z-index: 5;
display:hidden;
position:absolute;
}
```

and here is the html code

```
<div id="rightbox"></div>
<a href="#" id="rightarrow">Tes</a>
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/dUbUP/21/